# Aggregate coeffcients from linear regression with interactions [r]

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, linear-regression

I am trying to write a function that would take linear regression model, Design matrix X and would return marginal effects of our coefficients.

Marginal effects are given in regression's summary output. However, if we have interactions present in our model we have to aggregate the coefficients.

I have prepared a small example in R:

```
library(tidyverse)


# Desing Matrix for regression with interaction ---------------------------

X <- model.matrix(hp ~ factor(gear) + disp + mpg + wt + wt:factor(gear), data = mtcars)
y <- mtcars$hp


lm(y ~ X - 1, data = mtcars) %>% 
  summary()


# Model Interpretation ----------------------------------------------------

# Our reference category is 'Gear3'.
# Meaning that X(Intercept) is an intercept for Gear3
# If I want an intercept for Gear4 and Gear5 coefs Gear4 and Gear5 are deviations from refrence cathegory
# So Intercept for Gear4 is: X(Intercept) + Xfactor(gear)4 = 166.0265 + 30.2619 = 196.2884
# Same Idea hold for Gear5: X(Intercept) + Xfactor(gear)5 = 166.0265 -58.2724 = 107.7541


# Now if we want to interpret wt as a marginal affect, again we need to take into account our created interactions.

# Xwt is marginal effect of wt for the regrence cathegory (Gear3)
# If we want marginal Affect for (Gear4 cars) we need: Xwt + Xfactor(gear)4:wt = -6.4985 -9.8580 = -16.3565
# SAme Idea for gear5: Xwt + Xfactor(gear)5:wt = -6.4985 + 49.6390 = 43.1405

I would like to write a function that would take model object and desing matrix and would return a dataframe with our aggregated marginal effects:
```

In case given I want a function to return a dataframe:

```
# X(Intercept)gear3: 166.0265
# X(Intercept)gear4: 196.2884
# X(Intercept)gear5:  107.7541
# 
# Xwtgear3:-6.4985
# Xwtgear4:-16.3565
# Xwtgear5:43.1405
```

Where the marginals effects for interactions are already precalculated/aggregated for user.
So far I was able to create some concept that is not generalize enought.

Therefore, I would like to ask for any ideas how to write function using either `dplyr` or `datatable`.

Comment: Does `broom::tidy(lm(...))` do the job?

Comment: Nope. I am aware of broom tidy - it converts `summary` output into dataframe. No aggregation is performed thou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are just interested in the output or the way of doing it yourself.

Regarding the former, you can use the {interactions} package, which will give you your desired output. Regarding the latter, you could have a look at how the {interactions} packages calculates this output under the hood.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(interactions)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(gear = factor(gear))
fit <- lm(hp ~ wt * gear + disp + mpg, data = mtcars2)
slopes <- sim_slopes(fit, pred = wt, modx = gear, centered = "none")
#> Warning: Johnson-Neyman intervals are not available for factor moderators.

slopes$ints
#>   Value of gear     Est.      S.E.       2.5%    97.5%   t val.          p
#> 1             5 107.7540 103.74667 -106.36856 321.8766 1.038626 0.30932987
#> 2             4 196.2884 100.91523  -11.99042 404.5672 1.945082 0.06357154
#> 3             3 166.0265  71.71678   18.01029 314.0426 2.315029 0.02947996

slopes$slopes
#>   Value of gear       Est.     S.E.      2.5%    97.5%     t val.         p
#> 1             5  43.140490 26.69021 -11.94539 98.22637  1.6163415 0.1190910
#> 2             4 -16.356572 20.22409 -58.09705 25.38390 -0.8087667 0.4265945
#> 3             3  -6.498535 15.37599 -38.23302 25.23595 -0.4226417 0.6763194
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you want both results in one `data.frame` you could easily bind them together:

```r
bind_rows(mutate(slopes$ints, term = "(Intercept)"),
          mutate(slopes$slopes, term = "(Interaction)")) %>% 
            select(term, "Value of gear", Est., p)

#>            term Value of gear       Est.          p
#> 1   (Intercept)             5 107.754033 0.30932987
#> 2   (Intercept)             4 196.288380 0.06357154
#> 3   (Intercept)             3 166.026451 0.02947996
#> 4 (Interaction)             5  43.140490 0.11909097
#> 5 (Interaction)             4 -16.356572 0.42659451
#> 6 (Interaction)             3  -6.498535 0.67631941
```

Comment: Hi there this is nice step. However I want to write this as a sub-step inside bigger function that does some model precalculations. However, I think this is nice step to use.